# How do I render different data of an onClick event without updating the previous render?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, use-state, buttonclick

I'm creating a text based rpg using React/Context API/UseReducer, but first I wanted to practice using useState in order to render objects from an onclick event.  So far, I managed to render an object from an array, and the data that gets displayed is determined by what button I click on.  The problem is, whenever I render one object and go to click on another button, the new object gets rendered, and the previous object gets updated to that of what I currently clicked on.

For instance, I have 8 options to choose from:  Weak Strike 1-4, Mid Strike 1-2, Strong Strike and Launch Strike.  When I click on Weak Strike 1, that gets rendered on the page.  When I click on Mid strike 1, that also gets rendered on the page, but Weak strike 1 changes to Mid strike 1, so now I have two Mid strike 1s.

I need a way to render both Weak Strike 1 and Mid strike on the page without one or the other updating to match each other.

Code: State Hooks

```
const [name, setName] = useState(rpActions.strike)  //Used to set and update a strike action

const [count, setCount] = useState(0)  //Used to add a component after one button click
```

Code: onClickHandler

```
const onClickHandler = (e) => {

    setCount(count + 1)
    setName({...name, name: e.target.value})
    console.log(e.target.value)

 }
```

Code: Render Logic

```
 <button className="w3-button w3-purple" value={name[0].name}  onClick={onClickHandler}>{name[0].name}</button>
      <button className="w3-button w3-purple" value={name[1].name}  onClick={onClickHandler}>{name[1].name}</button>
      <button className="w3-button w3-purple" value={name[2].name}  onClick={onClickHandler}>{name[2].name}</button>
      <button className="w3-button w3-purple" value={name[3].name}  onClick={onClickHandler}>{name[3].name}</button>
      <button className="w3-button w3-purple" value={name[4].name}  onClick={onClickHandler}>{name[4].name}</button>
      <button className="w3-button w3-purple" value={name[5].name}  onClick={onClickHandler}>{name[5].name}</button>
      <button className="w3-button w3-purple" value={name[6].name}  onClick={onClickHandler}>{name[6].name}</button>
      <button className="w3-button w3-purple" value={name[7].name}  onClick={onClickHandler}>{name[7].name}</button>

 
{[...Array(count)].map((_, i) => <BattleSelection key={i} stkName2={name.name} />)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, your `name` variable should be an array instead of an object.

Your `BattleSelection` component reads the object `name`, which is updated every time you click a button. It doesn't matter the number of count, you're always be reading the last clicked value.

Also, since rpActions is a constant, you don't need to put it on a state variable:

```js
const [strikes, setStrikes] = useState([])  //Used to set and update a strike action

// you can also use value here, but maybe your strike object has more attributes that you might need.
const onClickHandler = (newStrike) => {
    setStrikes(_strikes => [..._strikes, newStrike])
    console.log(newStrike)
}
```

```
{rpActions.map(d => (
  <button className="w3-button w3-purple" 
    value={d.name}  // not necessary anymore
    onClick={() => onClickHandler(d)}
   >
    {d.name}
   </button>
))}

{strikes.map((d) => <BattleSelection key={d.name} stkName2={d.name} />)}
```

Answer (score 0):

`name` only stores the most recently clicked strike. When you map the array, `name.name` has the same value on each iteration.

Instead, you want to have a history of strikes. Create an array and append a new item on each click.

```
const [names, setNames] = useState([]);

const onClickHandler = (e) => {
setNames([...names, { name: e.target.value }])
}
```

render:

```
names.map((item, i) => <BattleSelection key={i} stkName2={item.name} />)}
```

Comment: I used some of the logic here to make it work with the logic imposed by Pedro's solution.  Thank you.